# Can I use JSTL <c:if> to allow a certain number of user inputs

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I am trying to make to allow the user to the decide how many notes they want to add. If the user decides 0, 0 input boxes appear, if 1 then 1, etc. I tried doing this with the following code, using  and . It's not working. Do I need to first have the user submit their choice

```
<td><select name="numberNotes" id="numberNotes">
<option value='0'>0</option>
<option value='1'>1</option>    
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
<option value='4'>4</option>    
<option value='5'>5</option>
</select></td>

<c:set var="userChoice" scope="session" value="${numberNotes}"/>
<c:if test="${userChoice == '0'}">
</c:if>
<c:if test="${userChoice == '1'}">
<td>Note 1: </td><td><input type="text" name="notes" /></td>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${userChoice == '2'}">
<td>Note 1: </td><td><input type="text" name="notes" /></td>
<td>Note 2: </td><td><input type="text" name="notes" /></td>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${userChoice == '3'}">
<td>Note 1: </td><td><input type="text" name="notes" /></td>
<td>Note 2: </td><td><input type="text" name="notes" /></td>
<td>Note 3: </td><td><input type="text" name="notes" /></td>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${userChoice == '4'}">
<td>Note 1: </td><td><input type="text" name="notes" /></td>
<td>Note 2: </td><td><input type="text" name="notes" /></td>
<td>Note 3: </td><td><input type="text" name="notes" /></td>
<td>Note 4: </td><td><input type="text" name="notes" /></td>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${userChoice == '5'}">
<td>Note 1: </td><td><input type="text" name="notes" /></td>
<td>Note 2: </td><td><input type="text" name="notes" /></td>
<td>Note 3: </td><td><input type="text" name="notes" /></td>
<td>Note 4: </td><td><input type="text" name="notes" /></td>
<td>Note 5: </td><td><input type="text" name="notes" /></td>
</c:if>
```

Comment: JSTL tags run on the server, *before* any HTML is sent to the browser. A user selecting a value in the combobox happens on the browser, *after* the HTML has been sent from the server. If you want to make dynamic changes depending on user selection, it has to be written in JavaScript, running in the browser. It cannot be JSTL running on the server.

Comment: @Andreas said it, I will too. JSP is "like" PHP, it runs on the server, the client will NEVER receive anything in JSP langage. If you want a dynamic behavior for the client, you need to use Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this will fall under Server vs Client Scripting.

All your `<c:if>` conditions can be optimized as below. where the ***endcount*** variable value needs to be populated from your selection list. (which might required a jquery/javascript functions)

```
<c:set var="endcount" value="5" />
<tr>
<c:forEach begin="1" end= "${endcount}" varStatus="loopCounter">
<td>Note <c:out value="${loopCounter.index}" /> : </td><td><input type="text" name="notes" /></td><br/>
</c:forEach>
</tr>
```